# UIAlertView code errors

Tags: ios, xcode4, xcode4.3, uialertview, alert

I'm creating a application for a iOS device but on the imagee below i have the some errors 
 [image]

as you can see there all the same but i have only had them errors sense i added the code for the links (apple,google,yahoo,

im not to sure whats gone wrong but i would really appreciate if you can help and tell me what i need to change to stop them errors.

---

As you can see there is only on of the show alert code below but i do have the other 10 in Xcode i just didn't want to take up all the space but i have named them like

showAlertOO
showAlert1
showAlert2
showAlert3
showAlert4
showAlert5
showAlert6
showAlert7
showAlert8
showAlert9

if you get what i mean

```
  - (void) showAlert {

        UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc]

                              initWithTitle:@"hello"
                              message:@"whats you name" 
                              delegate:nil 
                              cancelButtonTitle:@"Dismiss" 
                              otherButtonTitles:@"apple", @"google" , @"yahoo", nil]; 



        [alert show];
```

---

Ok so this is the code that i added to get my buttons to work and then this is what created them errors.

```
    -(void)alertView:(UIAlertView *)alertView clickedButtonAtIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex{

if (buttonIndex == 1) { [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.apple.com/uk"]]; 
        }
    if (buttonIndex == 2) { [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.google.com"]]; 
    }
        if (buttonIndex == 3) { [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.yahoo.com"]]; 
        }
```

---

all the code below is fine and i have no errors here i just wanted you guys to see the set up i have

```
 -(IBAction)plus {
        counter=counter + 1;
        count.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%i",counter];
        if(counter == 100)
            [self showAlert];
        if(counter == 500)
            [self showAlert00];
        if(counter == 1000)
            [self showAlert1];
        if(counter == 2500)
            [self showAlert2];
        if(counter == 5000)
            [self showAlert3];
        if(counter == 7500)
            [self showAlert4];
        if(counter == 10000)
            [self showAlert5];
        if(counter == 15000)
            [self showAlert6];
        if(counter == 20000)
            [self showAlert7];
        if(counter == 25000)
            [self showAlert8];
        if(counter == 30000)
            [self showAlert9];
        if(counter == 35000)
            [self showAlert10];
    }



    -(IBAction)zero {
        counter=0;
        count.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%i",counter];
    }




    - (void)viewDidLoad {
        counter=0;
        count.text = @"0";
            [super viewDidLoad];

    }
```

thank you very much for your time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you declare the selectors 'showAlert' ... 'showAlert10' before actually using them?.
If not, you could declare them in a private category (at the top of your .m file).

By the way... i strongly recommend that you use descriptive names, instead of 'showAlert5'. That could eventually save you some time going backwards and forward... and not just for this, i mean, everywhere in your code.

Comment: ok thanks for your advice how do i declare them then sorry its just I'm not the best coder lol

Comment: It's just a suggestion, no worries!. Please, let me know if you're still having trouble!

Comment: ok well Ive still got the same errors buddy so i guess I'm having trouble!

Comment: Is it building your code anyways?. Sometimes, the latest Xcode doesn't clean the previous errors, and builds either way.

Comment: well i have built the app and it worked fine all the alerts was show etc its just sense i add the code i said i get them errors and i just tried and build failed??

Comment: I've been trying now for over a hour and still can't figure it out please can you help

Comment: Hey there. That error means that the method signatures are not being found. If possible, could you post the whole class?.